# Perfectly correlated (normal) random variables

Tags: probability, correlation, normal-distribution

I am not sure in the terminology, so I will simply try to explain the situation that I would like to model as I see it. Suppose there is a set of random variables. The variables are correlated in such a way that they deviate from their expected values into the same direction all together. By this I mean that they can be either all together larger then their expectation or all together lower. Is it possible to model such a dependency with a multivariate normal random variable $\mathbf{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$, assuming the knowledge about the marginal distributions of the components $\mathbf{X}_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma^2_i)$? How to construct $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is this situation? Thank you.

Best wishes,
Ivan

Comment: If you require that there be no possibility of deviations from this correlated behavior, then these variables cannot be multivariate normal unless they all are linear combinations of a constant and one (univariate) normal.  But perhaps your restriction is not as severe as this?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the question, can't you just fill $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ in with the covariances from your dataset?

Comment: Thank you for the replies. The point is that I am trying to build a model of a quite complicated system and, in order to be able to at least start from something, I can make some assumptions that later, I hope, I will be able to get rid of or relax. Since multivariate r.v.'s are quite comfortable to deal with (and the nature is supposed to be fair), I have decided to start from them, but the correlation mentioned earlier is a must, it should be in the model from the very beginning.

Comment: @whuber, I also though about this possibility of having just one normal r.v. $\xi$, the rest are just linear transformations of it like $\mathbf{X}_i = a_i \xi + b_i$. May be I should start from this simple scenario.

Comment: @rm999, probably, you are also right. If one has a bunch of data, based on which s/he estimates $\mu_i$ and $\sigma^2_i$, s/he can also try to estimate the covariance matrix.

Comment: @whuder, can you please elaborate a bit on what you wrote? Why the correlation cannot be captured solely by a multivariate r.v. with an appropriate covariance matrix? If we have two r.v.'s and we know that they are "perfectly" correlated, then their correlation coefficient is 1, i.e., $\rho_{ij} = \frac{cov(\mathbf{X}_i, \mathbf{X}_j)}{\sigma_i \sigma_j} = 1$. Cannot we simply fill in $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ with $\sigma_i \sigma_j$?

Comment: Take, for example, two variables.  Any nondegenerate bivariate normal distribution will have a density with elliptical contours concentric about the point of means: this *guarantees* a positive chance of one being higher and the other being lower than its expectation.  Therefore it is impossible for a multivariate distribution to have the properties you describe *and* be multivariate normal.  @Stask describes a way to get a distribution like the one you want whose *marginals* have normal distributions--but it is not multivariate normal, of course.

Comment: @whuber, thanks, it seems to be more or less clear. Can you please also explain what I would construct if I took the approach mentioned in my previous comment with $\rho_{ij} = 1$? It seems that I am misinterpreting the Pearson correlation, because I thought it was exactly what I needed, i.e., when one variable increases another does the same. What am I missing here?

Comment: Pearson correlation measures a general *tendency,* not a deterministic relationship.  For example, even when $\rho=4/5$, there is still a probability of $\arctan(3/4)/\pi \approx 20.5\%$ that one value will be less than its mean while the other is greater.

Comment: @whuber: I disagree with your statement in that one can have a multivariate normal $\mathcal{N}_d(\mu,\Sigma)$ distribution _with perfect correlation_. Simply, in this case, the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ cannot be inverted and there is no density against the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: "I also though about this possibility of having just one normal r.v. $x_i$, the rest are just linear transformations of it like $X_i=a_i\xi+b_i$."  Just be aware that $\rho_{i,j} = \text{sgn}(a_ia_j) = \pm 1$ in this case, and if you know the value of _any_ of the $X_i$ (or $\xi$), you know the value  of_all_ of them.  Put another way, you cannot get two data points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ from this distribution such that _one_ of the variables has the same value and the other a different value: $x_1=y_1$ if and only if $x_2=y_2$. This _might_ not be quite what you are looking for.

Comment: @Xi'an I agree that there is no density function on $\mathbb R^d$ when $\Sigma$ is singular, but I think it is still correct to say that the random variables have a multivariate normal _distribution_, and the $(i,j)$-th element of $\Sigma$ is still $\text{cov}(X_i,X_j)$. Also, given, say, $10000$ samples from a $20$-dimensional distribution, it is not easy (at least for me) to just take one look and say "Hey, all of these points lie on this particular $19$-dimensional hyperplane in $20$-dimensional space."

Comment: I'm afraid we're not in disagreement, @Xi'an :-)  Please read my very first comment in this thread.  Note, too, that except when providing examples, I make no reference to *densities,* only to distributions, and I believe I've been careful about qualifying the densities as belonging to *nondegenerate* multivariate normal distributions.

Comment: @whuber: I am glad (not afraid) we are not in disagreement then! I think it is important to make the point that a multivariate normal distribution is well-defined by its means and covariance matrix and the fact that any linear projection of the normal vector is a normal variate.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: we are also in agreement! When $\Sigma$ is singular, $X$ remains a normal vector. As about your second point, it is actually _easy_ to spot the issue because the empirical covariance matrix shares the same singularity.

Comment: @Xi'an, regarding "one can have a multivariate normal distribution with perfect correlation", even if the covariance matrix cannot be inverted in this case, can you please show to construct it? As far as I understand, the rank of the matrix should be less than the number of dimensions, probably, just 1.

Comment: To construct $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$, find the eigenvalues $\Lambda$ and eigenbasis $B$ associated with $\Sigma$ so that $\Sigma=B^T\text{diag}(\Lambda)B$ and transform $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I)$ into $\mu+B^T\text{diag}(\Lambda^{1/2})Y$.

Comment: @Xi'an, thank you, I actually wanted to ask about $\Sigma$, how to construct this matrix in the case of our perfect correlation.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this very simple snippet:

```
    m1 <- 0
    m2 <- 0
    cov <- 0.8
    x1 <- rnorm(100, mean=m1)
    x2 <- cov*x1 + rnorm(100,mean=m2-cov*m1,sd=sqrt(1-cov*cov))
    plot(x1,x2)
    x2a <- x2*sign(x1-m1)*sign(x2-m2)
    plot(x1,x2a)
```

It folds the distribution of `x2` around its mean, aligning its deviations from the mean to those of `x1` from its mean. Of course the resulting distribution cannot be characterized as a multivariate normal, although each margin is normal:

```
    plot( density(x1), ylim=c(0,0.5) )
    hist( x1, add=T, prob=T )
```

[image: Contour]

*Contours of the density of (x1, x2a): the probability that would ordinarily be associated with values in quadrants II or IV has been symmetrically displaced into quadrants I and III, leaving the marginal distributions undisturbed.*

This is a classic (counter)example of a distribution that has normal margins, yet is not a multivariate normal; frankly, I don't know how to build any other ones.

The transformation increases the correlation somewhat:

```
    > cor(x1,x2)
    [1] 0.7999774
    > cor(x1,x2a)
    [1] 0.8575814
```

You would've seen a much stronger effect with lower `cov`, of course: you can start with `cov=0` and still get the correlation of the resulting variables above 0.6.

Comment: When starting with a bivariate normal distribution of correlation $\rho\ge 0$, this procedure produces a bivariate distribution of correlation $\frac{2}{\pi}(\sqrt{1-\rho^2}+\rho \arcsin(\rho))$, which ranges from $2/\pi\approx 0.637$ up to $1$.

Comment: @whuber, do you have a reference? Not that I am not ready to take your word for it, but to have a complete response. It would also be great if you could post the contour plot code if you have it at your fingertips.

Comment: The results in the comment are just a calculation.  (And you shouldn't take my word for it: I make mistakes.  But at least the formula agrees with your results!  It gives 0.854 for $\rho=0.8$.)  For the plot, here's *Mathematica* code:

Comment: $\text{With}[\{\mu=0,\nu=0, \sigma=1, \tau=1, \rho=\frac{4}{5}\},$
$g[\text{x_},\text{y_}] \text{:=}\text{With}[\{f = \text{BinormalDistribution}[\{\mu , \nu \},\{\sigma , \tau \},\rho ]\},$
$\quad\text{Piecewise}[\{\{\text{PDF}[f, \{x,y\}] + \text{PDF}[f, \{2\mu -x,y\}], (x-\mu )(y-\nu )\geq  0\}\}, 0]];$
$\text{ContourPlot}[g[x,y], \{x,\mu -2.5\sigma ,\mu +2.5\sigma \}, \{y,\nu -2.5\tau ,\nu +2.5\tau \},$
$\quad\text{PlotRange}\to  \{\text{Full}, \text{Full}, \text{Full}\}, \text{Contours}\to  12,$
$\text{PlotPoints}\to 100, \text{AspectRatio}\to  \tau /\sigma ]]$

Comment: Related to @whuber's calculation: [Recent MO question and answer](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88544/on-two-dimensional-gaussian-integrals).